# How to handle multipage form with Login/Signup on the end in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a form to submit a request to the website. In this form user will fill the form like, `subject`, `description` and some other fields, once user click on the `Submit` button the form validatation will work in background and the following operations should be called.

- First we need to check if the user is logged in then attached the
  user id with the form and submit that form.
- If user is not logged in ask for the login or the signup in the next page
- If user already registered, he will try to login, then process the login and submit the request with that newly logged in user.
- If user is not registered, then he will try to register and then register the user and submit the form with that newly registered user.

**Note:** I'm also thinking about the check the validation so if the validation fail during user login, registering then don't loss the form request data.

I have the following ideas in my mind.

1. Create a controller called as `RequestController` and then there
   create different methods as `dataCollectStep`, `checkLoginRegisterStep` `registeringStep`,
   `loginStep` so first call the `dataCollectStep` which will be first
   call and in the method check if the user logged in then submit the
   form with user logged in id.
2. If user is not logged in then add all the fields of form to the `session` and call the next method `checkLoginRegisterStep`.
3. If user click on login, then call the user `loginStep` and validate the login and if logged in success then get all the values from the session and submit that form.

But this idea is not looking good, because I have to create duplicate code as `login` and `registering`. And session managing is also looking difficult if the form is bigger then we need to destroy session one by one, because destroying all the sessions could cause problem for logged in user.

So is there any good approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your concept and it's really nice. I have check following thing in my own project and then I am giving you a full solution.

If you follow my all the step then it will surely solve your issue.

First of all, Laravel has inbuilt authentication system, which is too good. You should use that.

run this command in terminal

`php artisan make:auth`

This command will create login & registration in laravel. You can also customize it by googling.

This command will create Auth controllers in **Controllers/Auth**

This also create HTML in **resources/views/auth**

This command also create database tables in **database/migrations/.** You can run `php artisan migrate` to add migration in database.

---

> **MultipageController.php**

```
use Session;


class MultipageController extends Controller
{


    public function store(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();

        //First we need to check if the user is logged in then attached the user id with the form and submit that form.
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

            $input['user_id'] = $user_id;

        }else{
        // If user is not logged in ask for the login or the signup in the next page

            Session::put('filled_form', $input);
            return redirect()->route('login');  
        }


        //Your save code

        // Destroy form session here
        Session::forget('filled_form');

    }

}
```

---

> **Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

Add following method in LoginController which will keep the session data alive even after the logout.

```
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

---

> **Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**

Add following method in LoginController which will redirected you to the form url if it's have session data
You need to also print form data by get `Session::get('filled_form')` into each input.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{

    if ( Session::get('filled_form') ) {// do your margic here
        return redirect('form-url');
    }

    /* If not form filled then redirect where you want */
    return redirect('/homepage');
}
```

---

> **form.blade.php**

Get and print data into the form

```
<?php

 $subject = $description = '';
 if ( Session::get('filled_form') ){
    $form_data = Session::get('filled_form');
     $subject = $form_data['subject'];
     $description = $form_data['description'];
 }


?>

<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As best approach to check user is logged in or not and after that you allow user for particular action, you can do it by `auth` provided by Laravel.

You just have to run

```
php artisan make:auth
```

It will create controller's and views file which need for that.

And use `auth` middleware for not allowing user to submit form without logged in.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

At first you can run `php artisan make:auth`. After you can use middleware auth in your routing `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () { other routes here`.

Also you can use middleware in construct of the controller like this `public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}`

You can use current user id by `Auth::id()`;
After registration Laravel redirectes user to login page